# Mechanism of syndesmophyte growth in AS

Tags: human-biology, pathology, joints

Ankylosing Spondylitis (AS) causes inflammation around joints and the growth of syndesmophytes that may eventually fuse vertebrae. I'm familiar with the genetics (HLA-B27, IL1A) related to the condition, but I can't find any information about the mechanism that causes the actual growths to occur.

My current assumption is that AS causes the over-production or under-production of a particular compound or enzyme at the growth site, but I can't find any studies or papers that explain this. Is the mechanism known? Is it directly related to abnormal levels of a particular substance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember the pathology course from medical school, chronic long-lasting inflammation often leads to proliferation of connective tussie and ultimately to fibrosis.

The actual mechanism here is the lack of oxygen which is used-up by different immune system cells to produce peroxydes and superoxydes.

Comment: Interesting. So the symptomatic inflammation over long periods of time ultimately causes fibrosis and fuses the vertebrae? Also, what causes the lack of oxygen at the site?

Comment: Not only symptomatoc, any inflammation (including the idiopatic one) would do. There are many reasons for hypoxie here: decreased blood flow rate, swelling etc.